# Trace cause of Firestore reads

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am having an excessive amount of Firestore reads in the past few weeks. My system generally was processing about 60k reads per day. About 3 weeks ago it jumped to roughly 10 million a day and the past 2 days have hit over 40 million records in a single day! My user base has not grown, my code has not changed so there is no reason for this spike. I suspect an endpoint is being hit from someone outside the scope of my application that may be trying to penetrate or retrieve records. I have reached Firestore repeatedly for help with this as it becoming a huge loss every day this happens but they are unable to assist me.

Is there a way to trace an origin of read requests or more importantly see counts for which collections or documents are being read? This must be traceable somehow as Firestore bills you per read but I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no source IP address tracking with Cloud Firestore.  All reads fall under the same bucket, which is that "they happened".

If you're building a mobile app, now would be a good time to use security rules to limit which authenticated users can read and write what parts of your database, so that it's not just being accessed unlimited from anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Is it possible to use something like cloud functions to render a write or log for each read transaction? If I could do that even momentarily I could discover the source.

Comment: Source IPs can be faked or hidden with VPNs.  You're better off looking at individual UIDs that are authenticated with Firebase Authencation.  But whatever you need to do.

Comment: Log your read operations with Google Analytics. I have not seen what the charges or limits are with this, but just logging a read activity with the function and user info would get you somewhere.